# Mouse cursor goes crazy!

Tags: macos, mouse

This is driving me insane... All of a sudden my mouse cursor starts jumping and clicking around by its own. It doesn't look like somebody is remote controlling it. It rather is jumping around randomly, executing clicks or context menu commands just without any obvious aim.

This usually happens while I am working a while with the MacBook sitting on my lap. My feeling is that battery level could play a role here since the problem occurs only when the battery got drained down to below 50%. But it is just an impression. Could also have something to do with temperature, although I do not do CPU heavy stuff (just browsing).

I could do nothing against it. I switched off WLAN and Bluetooth. No fancy touchpad driver is running (though I had one running some time ago, called magicprefs).

There are some similar cases around the web but I did not find any solution yet.

Any help would be WOW,
rainer

PS MacOS X, most recent Mountain Lion, MacBook Pro 13"

Comment: Just curious - the computer still is usable, the mouse just will jump and click at random intervals? So it's normal, then jump/click, then normal, then jump/click?

Comment: The computer is fully usable, in theory. It is sometimes impossible to really use the trackpad, because the cursor is moving and clicking around. Then, for some seconds, you can use the thing as normal. But then it starts again... I put the computer yesterday evening to sleep, while connected to the power source and he was making this weird things. Today morning I opened up the lid and the problem was still there. He kept his crazyness while in sleep mode...

Comment: I know this post is old but I have the same issue now. Sometimes it's good for a month but then it comes back... the mouse cursor is shaking and when I click on a button for example it moves a bit further and goes to the wrong button... so annoying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went to my local mac dealer and it seems that the trackpad needs to be exchanged.

Update: It was definitely a hardware problem. Since the trackpad got exchanged, everything went back to normal. Most probably liquids found their way into the pad (a drop would be enough to mess everything up).

Answer (score 4):

unfortunately I´m experiencing the same thing since yesterday.
I don´t even touch the mouse  but the mouse keeps moving in a 3 to 5 seconds interval.

Did you proceed with this problem?

What I found so far:
- It is not the mouse (Magic Mouse) nor Bluetooth. Switching off both doesn´t change anything.
- It´s not in my account. Switching to another account is not the cure.

**I´m really embarrassed, but I solved the problem here.**

Yesterday my mouse battery was empty and I connected an old microsoft mouse with a cord because I ran out of loaded batteries. After reloading batteries I continued using Magic Mouse. But I didn´t disconnect the cord mouse but put it into a box. And since than I had tis problem. Removing the cord mouse solved the problem.

Comment: Hi,as you can read below: I had to exchange the trackpad. This is a common problem when the trackpad gets exposed to liquids like juice, water or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Some time, it happen because of humidity. you should try to sunbathe your macbook  for 15 minutes. if there is no sunlight in your country you can fix it with using hair dryer. Make sure your laptop is turned off before doing this job.
Note: Using of hair dryer must be 1 or 2 minute only on trackpad and keyboard. 
Hope! it will solve your problem.